# Typescript code dissappears after building in

Tags: typescript

I'm adding some code to a large existing Typescript file.
First, creating an array at the highest scope:

```
let events : any[];
```

Then, I'm defining a function that handles the list of events in the array.

```
setInterval(function() 
  {
    if (events !== undefined && events.length > 0) {
      ... do something ...
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Assume somewhere in the code events are added to that array.

I'm wondering why after building the application with yarn, when looking at the outputted javascript file, the function that handles the event doesn't include any of the code in the condition in the settimeout function.

It looks now similar to:

```
setInterval(function() 
      {
        if (events !== undefined && events.length > 0);
        // Please note there is no implementation here, it's all gone.
      }, 1000);
```

I'm rather new to Typescript, so maybe I'm missing the basic rules of when Typescript may omit some of the code when translating to javascript? Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: This is such a bizarre thing that it begs for a [mre].  Could you demonstrate this happening in code that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here)](https://tsplay.dev/wR9j5W)? My strong suspicion here is that something else is happening (e.g., you are modifying the ts file but it didn't re-compile when you built with yarn).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @jcalz, it helped me solve the issue. When trying to reproduce it in the playground, I noticed that the array was just declared and not initialized. When that happened, the code that used that array was omitted after building. Everything is working now after initializing the array. Thank you!

Comment: So would you say this is caused by a typo and wouldn't help others in the future?  Or would it help others if you were to write up a [mre] in the question and an answer to go with it?